# Exporting a list of ODBC Datasource drivers?

Tags: windows-7, odbc

Is it possible to export a CSV file of the list of database driver names from the `Create New Data Source` of the `ODBC Data Source Administrator`?

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]
[image: Create New Data Source]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/07/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-odbc-drivers-that-are-installed-on-a-computer.aspx) correctly describes how frustrated you feel? 
Obviously there is no easy way of getting this info... unless you consider upgrade to win 8 an easy way :-(

I used information in this article to make a powershell equivalent for you (you're on win 7 so ps v2 is installed by default):

```
get-itemproperty -path hklm:\software\odbc\odbcinst.ini\"Odbc drivers" |
get-member | 
where {$_.definition -match "installed"} |
select-object name | export-csv -noTypeInformation
```

Fire up powershell and paste above (you may need to press Enter key once or twice afer you paste). It will then ask you to give path - this is a path and file your data will be exported to (eg. `c:\temp\myDrivers.csv`) - press Enter - and if everything went well a file with driver list will be produced for you.

Edit: this will give additionally version and dll used.

```
get-itemproperty -path hklm:\software\odbc\odbcinst.ini\"Odbc drivers" |
get-member |
where {$_.definition -match "installed"} |
foreach-object { get-itemproperty -path $("hklm:\software\odbc\odbcinst.ini\"+ $_.name)} |
select-object PSChildName,Driver|Add-member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name FVersion -Value {(((get-item $this.Driver).versionInfo)).FileVersion} -PassThru |export-CSV -noTypeInformation
```

Comment: Well there they be...so hklm stands for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE of registry fame...I'll be darn....and if you dig into the registry there, you can find out things like what dll's make up the driver...and what file extensions it supports...however...I don't see a driver version...that's odd...I wonder where they store that...in the DLL maybe?

Comment: I looked at the properties of the DLL and that must be where it's getting the version numbers from because they match the ones in the "Create New Data Source" window.  The dates and company names are in there as well.

Comment: So it's probably possible to use something like this in the script (obtaining the driver filename first of course....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686/get-file-version-in-powershell)

Comment: @leeand00 I've changed script so it returns more data. Beware I'm not PS expert so it may be not best way to code that

Comment: On Windows 7 64-bit, the 32-bit drivers are found under the following registry path:
hklm:\software\wow6432Node\odbc\odbcinst.ini Note that some drivers found here (default Microsoft stuff), may not have a Path key-value pair, and will cause an error when running the powershell script posted in the answer, so some error-handling would have to be added.